# Android Development which folders to exclude for windows defender?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, windows-defender

I excluded the follwing folders in windows defender, but the "Antimalware Service executable" is still using a lot of cpu.

- `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`
- `C:\Users\ME\.android`
- `C:\Users\ME\MyAndroidProjects`
- `C:\Users\ME\AppData\local\Android`

Which folder/file did I forget?

Comment: The question to me really seems: Do you want to exclude any *folders* at all? -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/65423768/321013

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is now described in [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#antivirus-impact):

- Gradle cache

  ```
  %USERPROFILE%\.gradle
  ```
- Android Studio projects

  ```
  %USERPROFILE%\AndroidStudioProjects
  ```
- Android SDK

  ```
  %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\SDK
  ```
- Android Studio system files
  Syntax:

  ```
  %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\<product><version>
  ```

  Example:

  ```
  C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio4.1
  ```

Comment: I wish I had known this before I threw my laptop down the stairs due to lengthy builds...

Comment: Kirill Karmazin :D :D :D

Comment: What about `%USERPROFILE%\.android` ? Also, I think it's better to just have `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\` to include all versions there.

Comment: I'm not able to find settings in win 10 pro for exclude folder for win defender

Comment: Great job explaining AS system files with an example, Appdata is a hidden folder

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same problem.

After a deep search i excluded these folders, and it worked perfect. [image]